# How to update a local development plugin on a separate machine

Tags: plugins

I'm developing and testing a WordPress plugin , which is working fine on my localhost. I also have a development server that mimics my current WordPress setup. When I have new changes to my plugin, and want to push these changes to my development server, can I simply re-upload my plugin zip file to see my plugin changes on my development server? Or will that cause issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to create a git, you push from local to there and this plugin (or others, there are plenty):

https://github.com/afragen/github-updater

Syncs the code.

Good luck.